# How do I enable "mouse trails" in OSX?

Tags: mouse, accessibility

I have a lot of screen real estate, and am constantly "losing" my mouse.

I'd like to have a simple way of easily finding the mouse that doesn't have to be reconfigured when I undock from my 28 inch monitor and rely on my retina display.

Windows has a feature that allows for "mouse trails" so I can easily find the pointer wherever it is.  How can I get similar functionality on the Mac?

I looked under the "accessibility" tab but found nothing.

Answer (score 3):

There's no built-in option for that. You could try [HotMouse for $0.99](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hotmouse/id416410530?mt=12) in the App Store, or [OmniDazzle (free)](https://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnidazzle) if you're really feeling crazy.

Comment: None of these exist as of July 2016.  Simple Mouse Locator ($0.99) is available though.  Hard to believe mac doesn't have this baked in though.

Answer (score 2):

Under Accessibility - Display there is an option to make it larger, and thus easier to find.

Otherwise, go with one of Tortilla's options.

Comment: As of 10.11.5, this option no longer exists.

Comment: 10.11.5 has the 'Shake mouse pointer to locate' under the Display set of options in Accessibility.

Answer (score -1):

I use Pinpoint from the app store.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. We prefer answers contain some additional context, such as a link to the product in question and possibly steps to enable the requested features, if needed, or screenshots of the app in action.